# Connecting two databases in ASP.NET and Entity Framework 6 using SQLite

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to build a web application Using ASP.NET that displays stock information similar to this: 
https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:AAPL
It will have current data displayed at text and historical data graphed just as google has it.
That being said, all of my current data (EPS, P/E, etc) will be kept in one model, and all my historical data (At maximum 250 days) will be in another model. 
What is the best way to arrange the second model Having 250 columns plus a key seems unreasonable. Would it be best to have 2 columns, one for a foreign key and one for the 250 day data? I know this would result in several thousand rows if i want to have historical data for many stocks, so I was wondering what the best method of going about this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes having done something very similar before, I used 2 different models one for stock details and one for historical pricing

one for the current Quote (aka stockdetails Model)

```js
public class stockdetails
    {
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public decimal Ask { get; set; }
        public decimal AverageDailyVolume { get; set; }
        public decimal Bid { get; set; }
        public decimal AskRealtime { get; set; }
        public decimal BidRealtime { get; set; }
        public decimal BookValue { get; set; }
        public decimal Change_PercentChange { get; set; }
    // Rest omitted for brevity.
```

and one for Historical Data

```js
public class stockprices
    {
        public string symbol {get; set;}
        public DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Open { get; set; }
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can JOIN on symbol.  Good luck!

Additionally here are some URLs that should help you pull data modeled very similar to the 2 examples provided above

```js
string symbol = "MSFT";

string sYahooAPI = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + symbol + "%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

string sHistorical = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" + symbol + "?period1=1502226354&period2=1504904754&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=lhLzYrrUZPX";
```

Another URL you might find helpful - http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/